# WP Document Revisions and user groups with different permissions per group

Tags: wordpress

I have a question regarding WP Document Revisions.  I have a client with a parent company and 14 sister companies underneath it.  What they're looking to do is to have a document repository where all documents get stored, but the trick is that each sister company has their own financials that should stay visible only to top management in that sister company but needs to be visible to all Executives in the parent company.

I've looked into WP Document Revisions and it does pretty much what I want concerning the document part, what I can't figure out though is how to create user groups and setting permissions for those user groups.  In other words:

1. Set up an Executive Team group with permissions to view and edit the documents
2. Set up an Top Management group per 14 sister companies each with their own permissions
3. And then when the different users log in they should only see the documents that's set with their individual permissions.

Can anyone please help me with this, I've searched high and low but can't seem to find an answer, even if there's a different plugin that would better enable me to do the above, I'd be grateful for the help.

Regards,
Anina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the lead developer of WP Document Revisions. The above should be relatively easy to do as you described. There are two ways to do it:

First, you could set up a WordPress multisite install, and have individual subsites for each subsidiary, with one parent site for the parent corporation. Executives would have a login on all sites, while managers would have a login for their individual subsite, and for the single parent site. The advantage to this approach would be flexibility (if you'd like to use the workspace for other tasks, branding, etc.) but this flexibility would come at the cost of complexity (setting up 14 subsites).

The alternative approach, and perhaps what I would recommend depending on your needs, would be to group documents into a custom taxonomy (perhaps "companies"), and then base capabilities on what company the document is assigned to. This would allow you to have one single site, and could assign capabilities based on the proven and tested WordPress Roles and Capabilities system.

The functionality described in the second option does not yet exist out of the box, but is a relatively minor undertaking and is actually already under development for a potential "Pro" version of the plugin.

I hope the above is helpful. If you would be interested in discussing customizing the plugin to your needs, either as described above, or otherwise, please feel free to [contact me directly](http://ben.balter.com/contact/).

**Update:** *Updated link to contact information as Stack Exchange was blocking e-mail links.*

Comment: Hi BenBalter, thanks for the reply, I've seen this in another post before, the custom taxonomy bit, so I'll be investigating that next.  Thanks again.

Comment: I've got another question for you regarding the second method suggested above:  I've figured out how to do custom taxonomy but I'm not sure how i would add the custom taxonomy to the Documents section of WordPress.  To clarify, the Documents is displayed after I install WP Document Revisions in the left column.  I can see that it works with posts but if I register my taxonomy with register_taxonomy( 'companies', array('post'), $args ); it still doesn't show up when you edit a document?  Am I missing something here, or how would you tell the new taxonomy to show up in documents?

Comment: Hi BenBalter, not to worry about my last question, I've figured it out.  Thanks

Comment: 1) re: taxonomy, you're going to want to change `post` to `document`. 2) I am working on an out-of-the-box solution that should solve your problem. I am testing, and it should be available soon as an add-on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a working version of an add-on plugin that should do exactly what you're looking for. The file is here ( https://github.com/benbalter/WP-Document-Revisions-Code-Cookbook/blob/master/taxonomy-permissions.php ) and would be installed like any other plugin.

A bit more information is listed on the last question of the FAQ ( https://github.com/benbalter/WP-Document-Revisions/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions ), but in short, out of the box it will make a "departments" taxonomy, and will create capabilities based on any departments added. You would then install and activate Members, if you have not already, and use the interface members provides to add roles and assign capabilities.

You can tell the plugin to create and use any different taxonomy (e.g., "company" instead of  "departments"), as described within the file.

It may not be 100% stable as it hasn't been tested in the wild yet, but it should work. Please let me know if it works for you, or if you'd prefer to have me set it up, etc.

Comment: See also this discussion within the WordPress support threads -> http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-document-revisions-setting-up-teamsvisibility-roles?replies=4